# Copia de Vetores

Tags: c, matriz, array

boa noite!
Estou com uma dúvida quanto ao modo de copiar um vetor.

Declarei um vetor "matriz [a][j]" e preciso tirar a média aritmetica somente dos valores contidos em "matriz[a]", então preciso fazer uma cópia somente dos valores "[a]" para um vetor auxiliar, e não estou conseguindo.
Criei uma função que faz a cópia da matriz para outra, mas esta dando erro por que o vetor principal é diferente do auxiliar.

Segue o código da função copia:

```
void copiaMatriz (int matriz[], int vetorAux[]){

int count;
for(count = 0; count < LINHA; count++)
    vetorAux[count] = matriz[count]; }
```

Como devo declarar a matriz principal para que ele copie somente os elementos contidos em "[a]"?

Obrigado.

Comment: Por que acha que precisa fazer uma cópia? Não estou vendo o contexto geral, mas parece ser totalmente desnecessário fazer isto, mesmo que tenha o problema pode estar em outro lugar.

Comment: você pode usar o `memcpy` para fazer uma cópia do seu vetor, mesmo parecendo desnecessário nesse contexto.

Answer (score 0):

olá, acredito que você deseja fazer a media aritmética de uma linha de sua matriz utilizando um vetor auxiliar, portanto deveria declarar a matriz original com as duas dimensões`[i][j]`.

```
void copiaMatriz (int matriz[][colunas], int vetorAux[]){ /* pode-se usar um #define para as "colunas"*/

/* linha = linha da matriz em que se deseja copiar */

int i;
for(i = 0; i < linha; i++){
vetorAux[i] = matriz[linha][i];
```

ou, se preferir, pode fazer a média diretamente:

```
float media_matriz(int n, float mat[]["n"]) {  /* lembrando que não se deve utilizar a variavel diretamente na matriz sem antes defini-la, por isso as aspas */
/* n = numero de colunas */
float media;
int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
    {
            media = media + mat["linhaDesejada"][i];
    }
    media = media/("Colunas");

return media;
}
```